# Finding out complexity of a program when we use while loop

Tags: c, data-structures, time-complexity

What will be the time complexity for the following code?

```c
int fun1(int n) {
  int i = 1;
  int count = 0;

  while (i < n) {
    count++;
    i = i * 2;
  }

  printf("Loop ran %d times\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: its log n (base 2)

Comment: @Eraklon can u please explain to me this, it would be a great help

Comment: `i` is essentally `2^count` at the and of an iteration. If `n` would be 1024 then after 10 iteration `i` would be 1024 too so the loop would exit. log2(1024) = 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part of your code:

```
  while (i < n) {
    count++;
    i = i * 2;
  }
```

`i` is multiplied by `2` in every iteration.

Initially, `i` is `1`.
Iteration I:
`i = 1 * 2;`  => `i = 2`
Iteration II:
`i = 2 * 2;`  => `i = 4`
Iteration III:
`i = 4 * 2;`  => `i = 8`
Iteration IV:
`i = 8 * 2;`  => `i = 16`
.....
.....
and so on..

Assuming `n` is a number which is equal to 2<sup>k</sup>. Which means, loop will execute `k` times. At `k`<sup>th</sup> step:

2<sup>k</sup> = n

Taking logarithms (base 2) on both side:

log(2<sup>k</sup>) = log(n)

k log(2) = log(n)

k = log(n)              *[as log2(base 2) = 1]*

Hence, time complexity is O(log(n)).

Answer (score 3):

All sentences are O(1) and the loop does log(n) (base 2) iterations as `i` doubles itselves (`i=i*2`) every iteration, so its log(n) (base 2).

You can find more information here [What is time complexity of while loops?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-time-complexity-of-while-loops).

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of the above code is : `O(log(n))`

```
int fun1(int n) {
  int i = 1;
  int count = 0;

  // Here i runs from 1 to n 
  // but i doubles every time
  // i = 1 2 4 8 16 .... n
  // Hence O(log(n))
  while (i < n) {
    count++;
    i = i * 2;
  }

  printf("Loop ran %d times\n", count);

  return 0;
}
```

Suppose `n = 16  == 2^4`

In that case the loop will run only 4 time  `== 1 2 4 8 == log(16)`